# how category the all row based on cuontry save back to rdd with same format in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data like this

```
vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:sri
jhddasjd^country:UK;age:24;name:abhi
vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:shree
jhddasjd^country:UK;age:;name:david
```

in spark scala i need to identify country  categorized by  country saves as rdd same format 
should be in one rdd or file name us

```
jhddasjd^country:UK;age:24;name:abhi
jhddasjd^country:UK;age:;name:david
```

should be in one rdd or file name UK

```
vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:sri
vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:shree
```

Comment: Did you try anything? You basically need to filter on `country:US` and `country:UK` and then `saveAsTextFile`.

Comment: how segregate vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:sri
vxbjxvsj^country:US;age:23;name:shree

Comment: You need to provide the details of "firstparty1" and "brand_code". The code is not complete and hence help is not that straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read a file as a `RDD` you will get `RDD[String]` rdd of string, each line as a string.

To `filter` you need to `split` each line and extract the country field and filter on it

```
rdd.filter(r =>
      r.split(":")(1).split(";")(0).equalsIgnoreCase("US")
    ).saveAsTextFile(s"US"}")
```

This will get the country field and filters that is `"US"`

If you want this to be dynamic than you can grab the list of a unique country first and perform filter in a loop as

```
val countries = df1.map(_.split(":")).map(_ (1).split(";")(0)).collect()

countries.foreach(country => {
  rdd.filter(r =>
    r.split(":")(1).split(";")(0).equalsIgnoreCase(country)
  ).saveAsTextFile(s"output/${country}")
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, glad this helped you